# Laravel payment multi subscriptions

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am working on a SAAS project where users can create various projects. With each project, they can choose from 5 different plans. Each plan has its own costs per month. Hotjar is a kind of equal concept.

Now I want to arrange the subscription with Stripe. The problem with that was that a user can have a maximum x subscription, which of course was a shame. Then I decided to take 1 subscription that has several plans. But now I have a dilemma, to update the subscription you have to change the number via SubscriptionItem. Then you have to save yourself which plan has which SubscriptionItem_id for which user. That is quite a detour and can cause many problems.

Someone is a better way with Stripe or another payment software.

Comment: I’m not sure why you’re messing about with subscription items. You’d have one subscription product, with multiple pricing plans.

Comment: If you’re using Laravel, you might want to check out Spark: https://spark.laravel.com. It’s a starter for SaaS websites using Stripe to power subscriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to store the `subscritpion_item` IDs, you can look it up via the [subscription_item list API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/list?lang=php). All you need to do is store the `subscription_id` for your customers, and based on that ID you can retrieve the list of subscription_items:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_9GavlLpfiKewqeCBXvRvmVgd");

\Stripe\SubscriptionItem::all(["subscription" => "sub_EQlPGjVj4o5luH"]);
```

Then you can handle the `data` part of the returned JSON object and update / delete / etc these subscription items.

If you only have the `customer_id` handy, then you can use the [subscription list API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list?lang=php#list_subscriptions-customer) (with status as well on the GET params) to retrieve the list of active subscriptions.

Comment: When a new project is made i must check the `SubscriptionItem` with the same `plan_id` and change the quantities

Comment: Do you know what hotjar did?

Comment: @JurDekker with these API calls you can do just that - cross check the plan id with the subscription item. And I don't know what and how Hotjar handles their payments.

Comment: what you are actually saying is 2 calls 1 for get all SubscriptionItem and others for updating SubscriptionItem?

Comment: Correct. The first call is to get the items you need to update, and the second to update those. If you don't want to store the IDs yourself in your own database, this could be your solution.

Comment: What will you have done? put in the database or not?

Comment: I would store the customer_id in the database for sure, maybe subscription_id as well. But wouldn't bother with subscription_items, only rely on Stripe to keep track of those. Since their APIs are fairly open, this way I can check that list of subscriptions anytime and update if necessary.